# simple css triangle with gradient

Tags: css

i found plenty of ways to make triangles with css like this,

```
.arrow { position:relative; width: 130px; }
.triangle-left {
border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
float: left;
}
.triangle-right {
border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
float: right;
}
.tail { width: 20px; height: 10px; position: absolute; background-color: green }
.tail.left-arrow { left: 40px; top: 15px }
.tail.right-arrow { right: 40px; top: 15px }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apdms/

but all of them had a solid color background.

is there any way of making a simple triangle with a gradient (and a transparent background)?

Comment: with this code you just can fill the border with an gradient image, which is at the end more complicated than just using an image instead. you could use svg. see below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100" height="100"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     version="1.1">
    <title>triangle</title>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient y2="1" x2="1" y1="0" x1="0" id="flame">
       <stop stop-color="#ff0000" offset="0"/>
       <stop stop-color="#ffff00" offset="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path id="triangle" d="m0,0l100,50l-100,50l0,-100z" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill="url(#flame)"/>
</svg>
```

you can put svg markup into html. you could test if inline-svg can share the same css definitions from html ^^

Answer (score 0):

@coldelio, thanks for your answer, and although it works, 
it isn't exactly what i was looking for:
i was looking for a pure css way to do it, and i think i have found it (for -webkit only)

```
.arrow{
width:20px;
height:40px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
 }
 .gradient-triangle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    clip: rect(auto 30px 60px auto);
 }

 .gradient-triangle:after  {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,right bottom,left bottom,
            color-stop(.75, #52882d),
            color-stop(0,  #eee)
    );
    border: 1px solid #fff;
 }
```

[in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aT7cP/)

this is my first post here :)
so if you are reading this, i hope this code helps you..

Comment: in the fiddle it looks a lot like a rectangle to me :)

Comment: @JamieHutber Apparently it only works in webkit/blink. Most likely because it is using the old and deprecated `-webkit` linear gradient syntax. (and lacking other prefixes for `transform`).